# Strange error I cannot track down. C# .Net 4.0 Client Profile WIndows XP

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, windows-xp

When I try to load a windows forms application on a Windows XP system I get the following error which is captured in the ThreadExceptionEventArgs event.
This form works perfectly fine on a Windows 7 PC and is written in .Net 4.0 Client Profile.
C# 
Just to clarify this errors out before the form even shows on the screen. I have been trying to track this issue down for a few days now and I cannot seem to figure it out. I did verify that the XP machine does infact have .net 4.0 Client Profile installed on it. Is there something else that this can be in regards to XP and .net 4.0 
Here are my Usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Here is the Stack Trace report

Error Message :  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
 Stack Trace   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder) 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups() 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex) 
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader._LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode) 
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode) 
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode) 
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString) 
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase) 
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream) 
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name) 
   at HostedVoiceContract.Form1.InitializeComponent() 
   at HostedVoiceContract.Form1..ctor() 
   at HostedVoiceContract.Program.Main() 
 Sourcemscorlib

Inner Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect 
   at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height) 
   at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
 Target SiteVoid _SerializationInvoke(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a problem with an icon you used in the form.  Typically the Form.Icon property.

XP has limited support for icons, you cannot use the kind of "fancy" icons that work on Vista and up.  In particular, it can't be bigger than 256x256 and it can't be the kind that use a PNG image.

Comment: The icon files were 256X256 I read an article that they can't be bigger than 32x32 but that even caused an issue so I just removed it all together. Oh and it was an ICO file.